# how to compare 10 fields between two tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to compare a 11-column tableA against 11 of a 13-column tableB, and change a 12th column (indicator) in tableB on whether or not the fields match.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE `DDL_STAGING`.`MTDT_STG` S
INNER JOIN `REFERENCE`.`REF_DATA_MODELS` D
    ON S.`MDL_LAYER` = D.`MDL_LAYER`
    AND S.`SBJT` = D.`SBJT`
    AND S.`SCHEMA_NM` = D.`SCHEMA_NM`
    AND S.`TBL_NM` = D.`TBL_NM`
    AND S.`TBL_TYPE` = D.`TBL_TYPE`
    AND S.`CLMN_NM` = D.`CLMN_NM`
    AND S.`CLMN_DTYP` = D.`CLMN_DTYP`
    AND S.`NULL_IND` = D.`NULL_IND`
    AND S.`PK_IND` = D.`PK_IND`
    AND S.`DFLT_VAL` = D.`DFLT_VAL`
    AND S.`FK_TBL_ID` = D.`FK_TBL_ID`
    AND S.`FK_CLMN_ID` = D.`FK_CLMN_ID`
    AND S.`CLMN_ORD`= D.`CLMN_ORD`
SET S.ACTN_IND = 'U';
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

Naturally, this takes forever, and has locked up the workbench twice.
I tried to introduce hash checks so I can compare 1 column:

```
MD5(M.MDL_LAYER_ID |'~'| PKG.LOGL_PKG_NM | '~' | PC.PHYS_TBL_SCHEMA | '~' | PC.PHYS_TBL_NM | '~' |
        PC.PHYS_TBL_TYPE |'~'| PC.PHYS_CLMN_NM |'~'| PC.PHYS_CLMN_DTYP | '~' | PC.PHYS_CLMN_NULL | '~' |
        CASE WHEN PK.PHYS_CLMN_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE NULL END | '~' | PC.PHYS_CLMN_DFLT_VAL | '~' |
        F.Ttbl | '~' | F.Tcol) AS HASH_VAL
```

But when filling the columns, but some columns are null, which resulted in alot of null entries in the HASH_VAL column.  I can't compare there.

So I tried entering:

```
MD5(M.MDL_LAYER_ID |'~'| ifnull(PKG.LOGL_PKG_NM,'') | '~' | ifnull(PC.PHYS_TBL_SCHEMA,'') | '~' | ifnull(PC.PHYS_TBL_NM,'') | '~' |
    ifnull(PC.PHYS_TBL_TYPE,'') |'~'| ifnull(PC.PHYS_CLMN_NM,'') |'~'| ifnull(PC.PHYS_CLMN_DTYP,'') | '~' | ifnull(PC.PHYS_CLMN_NULL,'') | '~' |
    CASE WHEN PK.PHYS_CLMN_ID IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' ELSE '' END | '~' | ifnull(PC.PHYS_CLMN_DFLT_VAL,'') | '~' |
    ifnull(F.Ttbl,'') | '~' | ifnull(F.Tcol,'')) AS HASH_VAL
```

But that resulted in the SAME HASH Value for all recors.

What can I do here?  remember, the two tables only match 11 of 13 columns.
Thanks.

Comment: What indexes do you have on those tables? How many rows in the tables? etc...

Comment: I was thinking out of order.  I put the index on after I loaded it.  I changed it to add the index after DDL creation.  Put an index thing on as an answer so I can check it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as `JOIN` (and `WHERE`) conditions do not include `OR` or perform functions (such as `DATE`, `LEFT`, `TRIM`, etc...), appropriately constructed indexes can provide drastic performance increases.

*By "appropriately constructed" I mean indexes which have useful field(s) first in the fields they include; if you are joining/filtering only on "who" and your index is on "when and who" (in that order), it will not help you.*